# Using histogram to find the most common letter in an array

Tags: c

This is what I came up with, but I always get a Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'h' was corrupted.

```
int mostCommonLetter(char s[]) {
    int i=0, h[26],k=0, max=0, number=0;
    while ( k < 26){
        h[k] = '0';
        k++;
    }
    while(s[i] != '\0'){
        h[whichLetter(s[i])] = h[whichLetter(s[i])]+1;
        i++;
    }
    h[26] = '\0';
    for(i=0;h[i]!='\0';i++){
        if(h[i] > max)
            number=i;
    }
    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do `h[26] = '\0';` - h has 26 elements indexed 0..25. As you know the length of h you don't need to 0-terminate it, simply do `for (i=0; i < 26; ++i)`

Also, are you certain `whichLetter` always returns a value in the 0..25 range? What does it do if it e.g. encounters a space?

Comment: whichLetter returns -1 when it encounters a space

Comment: @user133466: That'll also break - you need to check for this and if the return value is -1, don't modify h

Answer (score 1):

This writes past the end of the array:

```
h[26] = '\0';
```

Make the for loop depend on the length rather than the last character:

```
for(i=0;i<26;i++){
    if(h[i] > max)
        number=i;
}
```